# Kubernetes - Google App Engine VPC connector

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, vpc

I'm using a VPC to connect my application to a remote database service, with App Engine, I just add the connection string to my app.yaml file :

```
vpc_access_connector:
  name: projects/ID/locations/europe-west1/connectors/database-connector
```

But I'm migrating the app to Google Kubernetes Engine, so the app will be deployed in Docker containers.

How can I reconnect to my VPC with GKE ?

Best regards

Comment: Your GKE cluster is already in your VPC. You don't need a special connector, YOU ARE IN! What's your problem?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to create/deploy your new GKE cluster on the same VPC as your database service.